# LdapRecord Laravel - Active Directory - does not see any users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, active-directory, ldap

I am using the [ready package](https://github.com/hurik/LdapRecord-Laravel-Example-Project) as a base, I have done all steps in the readme.md file and was able to login as "einstein" user. So all seems to be configured correctly.

Later I have changed the credentials for the ldap server, which is using Active Directory.

While runing command [php artisan ldap:test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIowg.png) i receive message that i was able to connect correctly. Laravel logs says the same, but I cannot log in to laravel app. While running the command [php artisan ldap:import ldap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euWXM.png) get message that no users where find

In the log file i see something like this:

```
[2021-04-28 23:04:08] local.INFO: LDAP (ldap://domain.pl:389) - Operation: Search - Base DN: cn=username@domain.pl,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=pl - Filter: (&(objectclass=top)(objectclass=person)(objectclass=organizationalperson)(objectclass=inetorgperson)(uid=username)) - Selected: (entryuuid,*) - Time Elapsed: 737.37
```

Have anyone had the same issue with the ldaprecord that he was able to connect to domain but wasn't able to authenticate to an app ? And was able to solve that ?

UPDATE: i've found that auth.php is using wrong User model, it was using OpenLdap not Active directory, changed that but result is still the same

Comment: What does your LDAP server log say?

Comment: found out what have i've done to make it work ... Test server is based on OpenLDAP - so while using that model in auth.php file, I am able test connection to the server / import users via command line and also login to an laravel app.

Comment: Destination server is based on Active Directory - while I've changed model for AD in auth.php file, I am able just to test connection and import users via command line - but I cannot login to an app with any credentials. Any ideas what shoud i check / edit to make i it work same way like OpenLDAP settings from test server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, to make it work with AD you need to:

- in the auth.php file switch model to ActiveDirectory
- in login controller change in the credentials function have to change 'uid' key to 'sameaccountname'